# showing notice:Trying to get property of non-object in Codigniter, when selecting an element from associate array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller

```
public function search(){
    $search_value=$this->input->post('search');
    $data['query']=$this->pro_model->searchData($search_value);
    image=$data['image'];
    print_r($image);exit();
    $this->load->view('viewData',$data);
    }
```

Model

```
public function searchData($search_value){
    $this->db->select('tu.unique_id,tc.*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_unique_id as tu,tbl_company_details as tc');
    $this->db->where('tu.unique_id',$search_value);
    $this->db->where('tu.id=tc.signup1_id');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
    }
```

I got this below error (image is my database field name.)

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: image
>
> Filename: controllers/pro_controll.php
>
> Line Number: 20
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\promise\application\controllers\pro_controll.php
>   Line: 20 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\promise\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Comment: Just to make sure, is `image` a column of `tbl_company_details`? Have you tried debugging the database result to see what's being returned? (The fields)

Comment: yes image is a column in tbl_company_details.yup i am getting result from database in $data when printing $data i am getting this array

Comment: i changed $data['query']['image'] but still getting Undefined index: image

Comment: `image=$data['image'];` does not compile.

Comment: Also that, @axiac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're storing the results inside

```
$data['query']
```

So you should be accessing it like so:

```
$data['query'][0]->image
```

Note that you access it as an object, not as an array. This is because `$query->result();` returns data type "object". However, if you are more comfortable working with arrays, you can change it to `$query->result_array();` and access it with `$data['query'][0]['image']`.

---

It might be that, depending on the query and function you use, it will return the row itself and not an array of rows, so you don't need to specify the index:

```
$data['query']->image
```